# Grails Springsecurity

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am developing an application using Grails.

I have been facing a problem,whenever i make some changes in domain classes the application automatically re runs  and when i try to refresh the page i receive access denied page and the log shows `user Id is null`.
here is the log

> Authentication attempt using org.springframework.deerwalk.impl.CustomCasAuthenticationProvider

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.usermanant.User.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: [1]
Possible solutions: getId(), wait(long), setId(java.lang.Long), getAt(java.lang.String), grep(java.lang.Object), wait()
 User:null
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you use in-memory database, your existing items will be deleted whenever you make changes to your domain model.

If you want to, you can insert your minimum Set of data into the bootstrap.groovy.

Hot replacing with real database like MySQL usually also requires restart of your application.

Comment: But why is user id null  just when application re runs

Comment: Probably because the session got invalidated.
You should get the same behavior if you access the page without loggin in a user in the first place.

Comment: Always restart the app when you save changes to a domain class

Answer (score 0):

In your Config.grooy (under Configurations) you have these lines:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com....User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com....UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com....Role'
```

You should have the correct class names here.

In your case:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName ='com.usermanant.User'
```